# How to initialise an variable sized int array to 0 in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I was trying out the insertion of elements program in C. There I need to initialise a VARIABLE SIZED ARRAY TO 0 but the compiler is not allowing me to do so. Any way out?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insert(int arr[],int k,int pos,int n)
{
    display(arr,n);
    int i=n-1;
    if(pos<n) {
        while(i>=pos) {
            arr[i]=arr[i-1];
            i--;
        }
        arr[pos]=k;
        display(arr,n);
    } else {
        printf("\n !!Array full!!");
        return 0;
    }
}


void display(int arr[],int n)
{   
    int i;
    printf("\n Displaying array elements: ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(arr[i]!=0)
            printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}


int main()
{   
    int n,pos,i=0,k;
    char c='y';
    printf("\n Enter the no. of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int arr[n];
    printf("\n Enter the array elements: ");
    while(c=='y'||c=='Y') {   
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        i++;
        printf("\n Continue (y/n): ");
        scanf(" %c",&c);
    }
    c='y';
    while(c=='y'||c=='Y') {
        printf("\n Enter the element to be inserted: ");
        scanf("%d",&k);
        printf("\n Enter the position: ");
        scanf("%d",&pos);
        pos--;
        insert(arr,k,pos,n);

        printf("\n Continue (y/n): ");
        scanf(" %c",&c);
        if(c=='n'||c=='N')
            printf("\n !!Thank You!!");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

when I tried out

```
int arr[n]={0};
```

it displayed an error that could not initialise a variable sized array to 0.

output of prog

Enter the position: 2

Displaying array elements: 2 5 3 **-344174192**
 Displaying array elements: 2 4 5 3
 Continue (y/n):

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.

garbage value is shown in bold.

Comment: Yeah I tried out that I displayed as error message given above.

Comment: The problem is that the array is `n` length, but you're trying to initialize a length of 1 by only setting the value of one index. The compiler doesn't appreciate that. You could always initialize it to `null` if that won't harm your functionality.

Comment: The language doesn't allow an initializer for a variable-length array. [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.9 paragraph 3: "The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length array type."

Comment: @tilz0R understood my problem and provided me the solution already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `memset` to clear your array:

`memset(arr, 0x00, sizeof(arr));`

When using sizeof with VLA, result of sizeof is not evaluated in compile time, so it is perfectly to use.

Edit: While your current approach works, I would strongly advice you to *move away* from VLA and in case you need VLA, use `malloc` and `free` functions. This will significantly decrease chances for stack overflow, in case of `n` being big number`.

```
#include "stdlib.h"

int main() {
    int* arr;
    int n;

    //Get n value by input

    arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * n);
    if (arr == NULL) {
        //No memory available, stop program
    }
    memset(arr, 0x00, sizeof(*arr) * n);

    //Do you job here just like before using VLA

    //At the end, before returning, call free function
    free(arr);
}
```

FYI, *VLA* stands for *Variable Length Array*.

Comment: That I can't because I am displaying the array elements after insertion of elements of user so clearing of array would lead to data loss.

Comment: But you want to clear array? You need to initialize array to `0` = *clear array*. So what are you thinking?

Comment: You call `memset` after declaring the array and before using it in the rest of the program.

Comment: Thanks @Christian Gibbons for making me understand what tilz0R actually wanted to say. Actually being a beginner I couldn't get what was said.

Comment: tilz0R, or simply: `memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr);` for an _array_.

Comment: I agree with both.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally the code snippet is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insert(int arr[],int k,int pos,int n)
{   display(arr,n);
    int i=n-1;
    if(pos<n)
{
    while(i>=pos)
    {
       arr[i]=arr[i-1];
       i--;
    }
    arr[pos]=k;
    display(arr,n);
}
else
    {
        printf("\n !!Array full!!");
        return 0;
    }
}


void display(int arr[],int n)
{   int i;
    printf("\n Displaying array elements: ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(arr[i]!=0)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}


int main()
{   int n,pos,i=0,k;
char c='y';
printf("\n Enter the no. of elements: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
int arr[n];
memset(arr, 0x00, sizeof(arr[0]) * n);
printf("\n Enter the array elements: ");
while(c=='y'||c=='Y')
{   
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    i++;
    printf("\n Continue (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c",&c);

}
c='y';
while(c=='y'||c=='Y')
{
    printf("\n Enter the element to be inserted: ");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    printf("\n Enter the position: ");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    pos--;
    insert(arr,k,pos,n);

    printf("\n Continue (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c",&c);
    if(c=='n'||c=='N')
        printf("\n !!Thank You!!");

}

return 0;
}
```